# Worst case runtime for Quicksort when a constant difference after partition is guaranteed

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

We want to sort with the standard quicksort and we are guaranteed, that, after calling the partition method, the size difference for both sections is at most a constant factor *a*. What is the worst case runtime for this algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### With limited size-difference between partitions, quicksort is worst-case O(n log(n))

Essentially, quicksort traverses the entire array each time it makes a split. Therefore, we need only consider the worst-case partitioning, and how many splits are required to get that down to size 1 (or 2).

Now, if we are guaranteed that the larger of two sections is at most *a* times as large as the other, then the worst case is where indeed the larger section is always *a* times as large.

In this case, the amount of "layers" in the quicksort will equal the amount of times we have to divide the original size of the array by (1+a)/a to get 1. This is equal to the logarithm with base (1+a)/a of the input size. Because *a* is constant, so is (1+a)/a, and therefore the amount of splits is O(log(n)), which means the algorithm runs in O(n log(n)) worst-case.